# What algorithgm Android's ActivityRecognitionAPI uses?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I am curious to find out what is the algorithm behind Google's ActivityRecognitionAPI on the Android platform to find out what is the current state of the user (e.g., i the user us walking, running or laying) and how it works in a nutshell? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's a classifier. The model is proprietary unless you can find a paper on it (and I couldn't). One interesting feature is that it is capable of providing confidences, so it is probably Bayesian.

Comment: @Emre thank you for your coment! I was looking for some sort of documentation about that with no luck so far.